# Showing Empty Array Value on Scope - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, express

why below resultArray variable showing empty on console log on scope ending. I tried let variable type also. Nothing seems to be working. returning also not showing any value. But Console log on same return statement scope showing values.

```
getAllQuery (query) {
  var resultArray=[];
    this.db.all(query, [], (err, rows) => {          
        if (err) {
          throw err;
        }
        rows.forEach((row) => {
          //console.log(row);
          resultArray.push(row);             
        });
        console.log(resultArray); //Here showing values
        return resultArray;//Nothing seems to be returning
      });
      console.log(resultArray); //Empty value
}
```

Comment: are you sure that `this.db.all` is a synchronous method? try doing the `console.log(resultArray)` before the `return resultArray;` line

Comment: the callback indicates that this function is to 99% chance asynchronous

Comment: how did you solve this problem please drop an answer

Comment: @Ogoh.cyril : see this, you could get an idea! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call